# Changing state with Immutable.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

The documentation for Immutable.js doesn't make it clear enough how to properly change the state using setState in React.js.

I have the following function:

```
createComment(comment) {

    const comments = Immutable.fromJS(this.state.comments);
    var tempList = comments.concat({
        text: comment,
        isAdmin: false
    });
    this.setState({ comments: tempList.toJS() });

}
```

It does work, but the problem is that the data is no longer immutable when you do this, which defeats the purpose of using Immutable.js, but the thing is that you can't pass an Immutable object to the setState function. So how are we supposed to do this exactly?

I know the data is no longer immutable, because I get the error:

```
comment.get is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read this guide: [Immutable as React state](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state). You don't need to call `.toJS()`.

This is totally fine:

```
const comments = Immutable.fromJS(this.state.comments);
var tempList = comments.concat({
    text: comment,
    isAdmin: false
});
this.setState({ comments: tempList });
```

Comment: Note that state must be a plain JS object, and not an Immutable collection, because React's setState API expects an object literal and will merge it (Object.assign) with the previous state.

Comment: Yes `this.setState({ comments: tempList })`; is working but `this.setState(tempList);` does't work because it receive an Immutable List. The example on github they don't use `.toJS()`.

Comment: comments is an immutable object. It cannot possibly work.